# error in google datastudio on using custom query

Tags: google-bigquery, looker-studio

I am using a simple sql block of statements to execute and return a set of results in big query, This is working fine in big query and getting the results,I need to export this data to data studio, so in data studio i use bigquery as connector and select the project and custom query and in that I paste the contents below:

```
 Declare metricType String;
    SET metricType="compute.googleapis.com/instance/cpu/utilization";
    BEGIN
    IF (metricType="compute.googleapis.com/instance/cpu/usage_time")
    THEN
      SELECT m.value as InstanceName,metric.type as metricType,point.value.double_value as usagetime,point.interval.start_time as StartTime,point.interval.end_time as EndTime,h.value  as instance_id FROM `myproject.metric_export.sd_metrics_export_fin`, unnest(resource.labels) as h,unnest(metric.labels) as m where metric.type='compute.googleapis.com/instance/cpu/usage_time' and h.key="project_id";
      ELSE IF (metricType="compute.googleapis.com/instance/cpu/utilization")
      THEN
      SELECT m.value as InstanceName,metric.type as metricType,point.value.double_value as utilizationrate,point.interval.start_time as       
     StartTime,point.interval.end_time as EndTime,h.value   as instance_id FROM `myproject-.metric_export.sd_metrics_export_fin`,unnest(resource.labels) as h,unnest(metric.labels) as m where metric.type='compute.googleapis.com/instance/cpu/utilization' and h.key="project_id";
    END IF;
    END IF;
    END;
```

but after click "ADD" button i get the below error:

[image]

I am not sure what is this error about? I have not used any stored procedure and I am just pasting it as custom query.

Also If I try to save the results of the BigQuery into a view from the Bigquery console results pane, it gives me the error,

```
Syntax error: Unexpected keyword DECLARE at [1:1]
```

I am extremely new to datastudio and also to bigquery. Kindly Help thanks

Comment: Try running the query in bigquery UI and then use in data studio. in that way the query won't have any problems

Comment: it is working fine in big query but datastudio gives this error code

Comment: @user1403505, instead of using scripting with `Begin`, have you considered using `CASE WHEN` ? Because in your query, the loop will never enter in the in the first `IF`.

Comment: yes, I will use that metrictype as parameter in datastudio, so that it will enter both loops, now it even syntax error for declare keyword

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I would like to make some considerations about your query. You are using [Scripting](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/scripting) in order to declare and create a loop within your query. However, since you declare and set the `metricsType` in the beginning of the query, it will never enter in the first `IF`. This happens because the value is set and it is not looping through anything.

I would suggest you to use `CASE WHEN` instead, as below:

```
SELECT m.value as InstanceName,metric.type as metricType,     
      CASE WHEN metric.type = @parameter THEN point.value.double_value ELSE 0 END AS  usagetime,
      CASE WHEN metric.type = @parameter THEN point.value.double_value ELSE 0 END AS utilizationrate,
      point.interval.start_time as StartTime,point.interval.end_time as EndTime,h.value  as instance_id 
FROM `myproject.metric_export.sd_metrics_export_fin`, unnest(resource.labels) as h,unnest(metric.labels) as m 
WHERE metric.type=@parameter and h.key="project_id";
```

Notice that I am using the concept of [Parameterized queries](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/parameterized-queries). Also, for this reason this query won't work in the console. In addition, pay attention that whem you set the `@parameter` to `"compute.googleapis.com/instance/cpu/utilization"`, it will have a ***non-null*** column with the `usagetime`  and a ***null*** column named `utilizationrate`.

Secondly, in order to add a new data source in DataStudio, you can follow this [tutorial from the documentation](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/6370296?hl=en). After, selecting ***New Report***, click on the ***BigQuery Connector*** > ***Custom Query***> ***Write your Project id***, you need to click in **ADD PARAMETER** (below the query editor). In the above query, I would add:

- **Name:** *parameter*
- **Display name:** *parameter*
- **Data type:** *text*
- **Default value:** leave it in blank
- Check the box ***Allow "parameter" to be modified in reports***. This means you will be able to use this parameter as a filter and modify its value within the reports.

Following all the steps above, the data source will be added smoothly.

*Lastly, I must point that if your query ran in the Console you are able to save it as a view by clicking on ***Save view***, such as described [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/views#creating_a_view).*

Comment: Thanks for this very much I will try this